# Upload a file with a POST request in php

Tags: php, upload

I have problems during the upload of a zip file to my server.
The move_uploaded_file function fail every time. I don't understand the problem. The folder permission are 777 and the file size is about 2 Mb.

```
<html>
  <body>

    <form action="../API/upload_zip.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Zip" name="submit">
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

-

```
<?php
    $target_dir = "../uploads/";
    $machineID="H725";
    $path=$target_dir.$machineID;
    if (!file_exists($path)) 
    {
        if(!mkdir($path, 0777, true)) die('Failed to create folders 1...');

        chmod($path, 0777);
    }      

    $pathWithData= $path."/".date("Y_m_d_h_i");
    if (!file_exists($pathWithData)) 
    {
        if(!mkdir($pathWithData, 0777, true)) die('Failed to create folders 2...');

        chmod($pathWithData, 0777);
    } 

    $final_path = $pathWithData ."/". basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    echo "PATH: ".$final_path."<br>";


    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $final_path))
    {
        echo "<br>The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "<br>Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting a permission denied error or something else? Also, does it happen with a small file, say 10kb?

Comment: You have error reporting on?

Comment: this is the content of $final_path "../uploads/H725/2015_02_09_09_26/Archive.zip" that is correct, and on the server the two folder are create without problem

Comment: Can you tell me what option of the php.ini I have to change for large file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be sure, but your host has a `file_uploads = On`, right? Check php.ini or create a `phpinfo();`

Also, try echoing your *$_FILES* with a `var_dump($_FILES);` The [error] should be 0 if there's no problem right in upload. These are the returning error constants:

```
UPLOAD_ERR_OK: 0
UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: 1
UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: 2
UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: 6
UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: 7
UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: 8
UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: 3
```

In php.ini, change these values:

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

Comment: file_uploads is on and I have incremented the maximum file size to 150Mb. this is the content of var_dump($_FILES): array(1) { ["fileToUpload"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(11) "Archive.zip" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(1) ["size"]=> int(0) } }

Comment: So the problem is this UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini. thank you!

Comment: Can you tell me what option of the php.ini I have to change for large file??

Comment: Check my updated answer, you have to change the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`

Comment: I understand the problem, I changhe the php.ini in php5 folder and not the php.ini present in apache2. Now it works fine. Thank you very much.